# Bash Substring Removal with Paths

Tags: bash

This must be a newbie mistake.  I am trying to slice off the head of a path stored as a string.  Why does it seem like I can't store the search pattern string in a variable?  Looking on the LDP it looks like you can do this.

(http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html and navigate to substring removal)

```
test="/Users/Kieran/foo/bar/"

echo ${test#/Users/Kieran}
result: /foo/bar/

test_dir="/Users/Kieran"

echo ${test#test_dir}
result: /Users/Kieran/foo/bar/
```

Thanks in advance for any responses.  Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo ${test#test_dir}
```

should be

```
echo "${test#"${test_dir}"}"
```

or simply

```
echo "${test#$test_dir}"
```

since you wanted to expand the values from `test_dir`. More about parameter expansion here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html